# is it possible to create vmcore file?

Tags: virtualbox, sysrq

here is my system:
base os: ubuntu 16.04

ubuntu 18.04 on virtualbox
mem 4G
cpu 2core

check kdump-config show
it said "ready to kdump"

then
sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=1

to make crash 
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger

after then 
screen is freezing 
also there is no response
I waited more then 10 minutes
there is no rebooting

I can't understand why can not make vmcore file at /var/crash

could you help me?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it about 5 days ago. I took several crash dump tests and confirmed that they were performed perfectly.

The reason why the crash dump was not performed was because of the Virtualbox option issue, and the resolution was as follows:

1. Settings -> Mother board -> I/O APIC~~ uncheck:** Virtualbox default is check
2. Settings -> Processor -> PAE/NX check and VT-X /AMD-V check** : Virtualbox default is uncheck

For your information, my Ubuntu version is 18.04, Virtualbox version is 6.1.14.

Comment: Virtualbox version is 6.1.14 instead of 16.1.14, isn't it ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake Virtualbox version is 6.1.14.I will update the answer with correct Virtualbox version.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work for me